# Что неправильно в скрипте для создания хеш-таблиц на основе данных, хранящихся в файле XML dz121.xml

Tags: xml, powershell, хеширование

Сначала я написал скрипт, который создаёт файл
$xml = [xml]$($processes| Select-Object Name, ID, StartTime,
PagedMemorySize | ConvertTo-Xml -Depth 2)
$xml.Save( $( Resolve-Path ./ ).Path + "\dz121.xml" )

```
$XMLdata = [xml]$(Get-Content .\dz121.xml) 
$ht = @{}
$XMLdata.ChildNodes | Foreach {$ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value}
$ht
```

Вот что я попытался сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как написать скрипт?

Comment: $XMLdata = [xml]$(Get-Content .\dz121.xml) 
$ht = @{}
$XMLdata.ChildNodes | Foreach {$ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value}
$ht